# XSLT - when case not showing

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements

I'm still learning XSLT and when I tried to show the value of a node with the 'when' function, just not showing up.

I'm figured out the input xml(because dspace don't show me anything):

```
<dc>
 <creator>
  <nameIdentifier> Caro </nameIdentifier>
  <nameIdentifierScheme> URI </nameIdentifierScheme>
  <nameScheme> Test </nameScheme>
  <creatorName> Roger </creatorName>
 </creator>
</dc>
```

My code:

```
<dc:identifier>
 <xsl:for-each select="doc:metadata/doc:element[@name='dc']/doc:element[@name='creator']/doc:element">
   <xsl:choose>            
     <xsl:when test="@name='nameIdentifierScheme'">
       <xsl:attribute name="nameIdentifierScheme">
         <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
       </xsl:attribute>

     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:when test="@name='nameIdentifier'">
       <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
     </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:for-each>
</dc:identifier>
```

With the code above the result is printing just one case:

```
 <dc:identifier>570</dc:identifier>
```

And what to do is:

```
    <dc:identifier nameIdentifierScheme="URI" >570</dc:identifier>
```

I need help to understand why does this happen. Thank you! :)

Comment: Please add also the input XML file.

Comment: Hi, I can't put the input XML because it's on dspace. :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the shared XSLT, it looks like you are trying to loop through all the child elements of `<creator>` which is not required to get the desired output. Please note `<xsl:for-each>` does not loop through the elements in an iterative manner like other programming languages. It won't be a case in which during the first iteration the element `nameIdentifierScheme` is located and its value assigned to the attribute and then in the next iteration `nameIdentifier` is located and its value assigned to `identifier`.

In order to get the desired output i.e. `<identifier>` element with an attribute `@nameIdentifierScheme` you can use the following code.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <identifier>
        <xsl:attribute name="nameIdentifierScheme">
            <xsl:value-of select="dc/creator/nameIdentifierScheme" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="dc/creator/nameIdentifier" />
    </identifier>
</xsl:template>
```

This template when applied on the shared XML

```
<dc>
    <creator>
        <nameIdentifier> Caro </nameIdentifier>
        <nameIdentifierScheme> URI </nameIdentifierScheme>
        <nameScheme> Test </nameScheme>
        <creatorName> Roger </creatorName>
    </creator>
</dc>
```

provides the following output

```
<identifier nameIdentifierScheme=" URI "> Caro </identifier>
```

If you want to get rid of the extra `spaces` in the values, you can use the `normalize-space()` function.